# Incorrect code coverage using nyc with Jest Based E2E Test Framework

Tags: code-coverage, instrumentation, istanbul, nyc

I am trying to generate code coverage for the single e2e test case. Here is what I did to achieve this.

1. Instrumented files related to e2e test case using nyc. Note here I used in place instrumentation
2. Executed test cases.
3. stored coverage report using `window.__coverage__` into `.nyc_output/coverage.json`.
4. generated report using `nyc report --reporter=lcov --reporter=text` command. created coverage folder

**I can see that its showing branches , lines statements functions of instrumented code. Actually it should show statement , lines of original code.**

Here is my nycrc file.

```
 {
  "extends": "nyc-config-tsx",
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.test.tsx",
    "**/*.mock.tsx",
    "**/*.test.ts",
    "**/*.mock.ts"
  ],
  "extension": [
    ".js",
    ".ts",
    ".jsx",
    ".tsx"
  ],
  "exclude-after-remap": false,
  "all": true,
  "cache": false,
  "source-map": true,
  "produce-source-map": true
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you manage to resolve the issue? I have absolutely the same setup and whatever I try - I still receive coverage for instrumented code.

Comment: @VyacheslavPalamar I did git restore in script to produce original code.